# How do I investigate the cause of my PC's boot failure?

Tags: boot, motherboard, hardware-failure

It happened today. My PC whilst running, suddenly froze and when I rebooted it, it wouldn't even boot to BIOS, but it gets powered on. I think the cause for that might have been a sort of physical jerk on my motherboard. That being said, could someone guide me on how to investigate the fault?

Comment: Did you try removing the power cord, the coin battery, and etc to do a full reset on your motherboards BIOS?  Refer to your mobo manual for instructions, and many are slightly different.  Some you can just short 2 pins together, some removing the power,battery, and then shorting pins, or etc.

Comment: @cybernard I removed the power cord etc with no success

Comment: Did you reset your BIOS?  Check the power supply make sure the  5v and 12v are + or - 5%.  If you have a spare try it.

Comment: Power off and try to reseat the motherboard and other connectors.

Comment: @cybernard I cleared CMOS but still no results. It's as of it didn't change a thing. The power supply is fault free.

Comment: @DrMoishe Pippik I did that to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

We can try the following methods to troubleshoot the issue:

1. If it is a laptop, do not use the charger and remove the battery, then press the power button for more than one minute.
   If it is a desktop computer, do not use the power supply, press the power button for more than one minute.
   Through the above operation to see if we can boot to the BIOS.
2. This issue may also be caused by HDD. If we are using a mechanical hard disk, we try to check if the hard disk has bad sectors and use the hdtune software to detect it.
   If it can be turned on, it will be detected on the computer. If it cannot be turned on, we need to remove the hard disk and install it on other computers to detect it.
3. The motherboard needs special tools. There is a tool called **debug card**. We plug it into the memory slot to check if the motherboard is faulty. But we need to buy this tool, which may be a bit expensive.
4. Is our PC still under warranty? If it is, it can be sent to the manufacturer for testing. If it is not under warranty, we can check with a third-party repairer.

Comment: Thanks for telling me about that. Also, I'd like to state that I finally got my PC(desktop) to work by simply taking out the processor and reinserting it. Do you know what may have caused this issue to be solved

Comment: Maybe the processor is loose during use.

Comment: I did think of that, but I don't think that should happen since it's so well clamped.